# Twitter API v1.1 Multiple Users One Feed

Tags: api, twitter

How can I retrieve the latest tweets for multiple users on Twitter and display them in one feed?

I can only seem to find ways to pull one account using the API v1.1

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Retrieve the tweets from user #1 and store in a list.
2. Retrieve the tweets from user #2 and store in the same list.
3. Sort the list by the timestamps of the tweets.
4. Display the list.

Comment: is there a more efficient way for more than 2 users? I don't like the multiple calls to the api, seeing as how you are limited by twitter.

Comment: The only other way I see to accomplish this would be to create a Twitter list (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/create.json), and add the users you wish to track to that list.  You could then call https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json to get all of the tweets of all of the people in that list.